# How to store and load huge images dataset?

Tags: python, image, numpy, pickle, conv-neural-network

I have a large image dataset to store. I have 300,000 images. Each image is a vector of 28800 pixels, which means that I have a matrix of `(300000, 28800)`

I stored that as follow

```
img_arr = np.stack(images, axis=0)

np.savetxt('pixels_dataset_large.csv',img_arr,delimiter=",")
```

However it takes long time to load it and some times l get memory error :

```
data_pixels=np.genfromtxt("pixels_dataset_large.csv", delimiter=',')
```

Is there any alternative to optimally store and load it ?

Comment: What's wrong with `np.save`/`np.load`? It saves the data as it is in memory, so no parsing is involved and the process is going to be as fast as the disk allows.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, l do have probelm only  with loading.  when l try np.load() l get TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Comment: This means you're using `load` incorrectly. [It doesn't have a `dtype` argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Comment: l did the following np.load("pixels_dataset_large.csv", delimiter=','). there is no dype parameter to put in load() !!

Comment: Then a [mcve] is in order.

Comment: Ivan recommended storing a binary representation which is much more clever (save, load). You seem now to use np.load (again: binary!) to load your text-based (non-binary!) stuff saved with savetxt (reading binary-repr will never take delimiter-info). Of course that won't work! (so basically: savetxt <-> genfromtxt; save <-> load). [numpy's docs on load even gives a complete example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're saving 300,000 x 28,000 data to csv, then assuming a float representation you're looking at an output file size of just shy of a terabyte, depending on the precision of the output. Even if you have a terabyte of disk space lying around, CSV is incredibly inefficient at this scale.

I'd suggest some binary storage scheme in this case (e.g. hdf5). You might check out the [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) package: it's pretty well-suited to working with dense array data of this size, it has an API that's very similar to NumPy, and it even leverages [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/) for transparent support of parallel and/or memory-mapped computation.